# Drupal 7: Using "global $user" secure?

Tags: php, security, drupal, drupal-7

In Drupal 7: Is there any major security issue manually using php to pull from `global $user`. Such use as displaying content to specific a role(s) in my case. Or is it best practice to stick to strictly using Views/Panels/Blocks in the CMS to hide/display content?

Exam: `if (in_array('moderator', $user->roles)){//reveal editable links}`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code you're implementing is secure (ie: there's no chance that the $user object can be overwritten and allow higher privileges to a lower-privileged user), there's nothing inherently insecure about using the global $user object.

That said, it's best practice to use views/blocks/panels wherever possible, to maintain a consistent and maintainable implementation.

Without more specific details, that's the most I can offer. Feel free to update your question and I will add more.

Comment: I have bounced back and forth on doing it manually with `global $user` to create quick edit buttons through my sites for clients to use. Been easier to control exactly what they can access.

Just wanted to know if it's even a secure method compared to using the CMS to control this. 

Thanks for the info.